# How To Make a channel Secure ? I'm using a Amf channel , How to add security to My channel

Tags: apache-flex, security, blazeds, lcds

I'm using a Amf channel , How to add security to My channel..

Comment: Secure against which attacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the channel def's, you'll find them in:

```
WEB-INF/flex/services-config.xml
```

Change or add a secure definition and endpoint - here is an example:

```
<channel-definition id="my-server" class="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel">
    <endpoint uri="http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/amf" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint" /> 
</channel-definition>
<channel-definition id="my-server-secure" class="mx.messaging.channels.SecureAMFChannel">
    <endpoint uri="https://{server.name}:443/{context.root}/amf" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.SecureAMFEndpoint" />
</channel-definition>
```

Notice the class must be different as well as you're connecting over SSL  (https / port 443)

Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Send it over SSL and use SecureAMFChannel.

Comment: how to Send it over SSL ?i have never done that before,,any links to .. how to implement SSL..???